# How to get Avalilable lookup columns in Loookup transformation into Lookup not match output path in ssis?

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

Can anyone suggest how to get **Available lookup columns** in Loookup transformation into **Lookup No match ouput** path?

please suggest me any way how can I get those columns in **Available lookup columns** into **Lookup No match ouput path**?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't have those columns in the "No match output" is that there is no data to be had.

If you need those columns in that path, then add a Derived Column Component after the Lookup to inject those columns. Use the appropriate NULL type to get a consistent meta data.

Or if you don't care whether you have no matches, just redirect no match to the match output and you'll have those columns already defined and they'll be empty.